# C++: Calling class object

Tags: c++, object

I'm new to programming and currently learning C++.

I would like to know if it's possible to call a class object using a variable. Something along this line.

E.g

```
class name
{
  ...
  void getFirstName()
  {
    return FirstName;
  }
}

name student1;
string testName = "student1";

testName.getFirstName(); // Returning FirstName
```

I know this doesn't work, but am quite interested to know if there's a way around it.

Thanks all.

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) maybe?

Comment: Why would you want to use such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

Put the declaration of testName inside your class definition, but don't initialize it there.

```
class name
{
  ...
  void getFirstName()
  {
    return testName;
  }
  ---
  string testName;
}

name student1;
student1.testName = "student1";

student1.getFirstName(); // Returning FirstName
```

This is a modification of your example that I hope address your question. I left the names alone to keep it closer to your original code, but you will probably want to rename "testName" to "firstName" or something along those lines.